# Count agrupando por semana

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Tenho uma tabela no MySQL e estou tentando agrupar ela por semana(pode ser semana do ano)

```
Select count(id),month(data_tarefa), year(data_tarefa) from tarefas group by mes, ano
```

Assim funciona legal, mas eu precisaria agrupar por semana, pesquisei e não achei uma função para retornar a semana do ano, se alguém tiver alguma dica agradeço.

Comment: de uma olhada aqui http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php

Comment: Tentei isso, mas não pareceu funcionar pra mim, de qualquer forma obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há uma função do MySQL que te dá uma concaternação entre o ano e a semana do ano, chamada `YEARWEEK()`. Use-a para ter o que você quer.

```
SELECT count(id), YEARWEEK(data_tarefa) anosemana
FROM tarefas
GROUP BY anosemana;
```